# Appending duplicate javascript object

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I'm working on a simple timer in JS. The problem is that the resulting code only shows one set of divider colons.

```
var divider = $('<span>').addClass('divider').text(':');
stopwatchFace = stopwatchFace.append(timeHour).append(divider)
                             .append(timeMin).append(divider).append(timeSec);
```

Is there a reason why the first one isn't being picked up? Should I be explicitly defining a divider1 and a divider2 object?

Comment: You don't need to use chaining in this case. [`jQuery.fn.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/#additional-arguments) appends all parameters that it receives.. so you can use something like:
`stopwatchFace.append(timeHour, divider, timeMin, divider.clone(),timeSec);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you append an already-appended element, the result is that it is moved.

You need to clone the element. In vanilla JS, this would be as simple as `divider.cloneNode(true)`.
In jQuery it's simple too: `divider.clone()`. Thanks Boaz for the info ^_^

Comment: The jQuery equivalent is the `.clone()` method.

Comment: @Kolink I have quite a strange question what is vanilla JS ? :)))

Answer (score 2):

Use need to clone divider. as divider is a dom single element cant exist two place at same time.

```
var divider = $('<span>').addClass('divider').text(':');
stopwatchFace = stopwatchFace.append(timeHour).append(divider.clone())
                             .append(timeMin).append(divider).append(timeSec);
```